# Gogs error - Public key content has been used

Tags: gogs

I'm unable to add the public key in my gogs account. only one user of my team could add the key and for him all functionalities are working fine. Anyone else is unable to add key, we have tried to add many putty key pairs but but each time we're getting same error - " Public key content has been used". After spending almost 1 day, i couldn't find the solution. We've tried everything that we could find in internet but we're still facing same issue. I've access of gogs server and database, we're using mssql as database for gogs. Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: Known bug: [https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/4509](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/4509) posted on GoGS over 1 year ago. Unfortunate this issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL Hack we are using:

Change the SHA256 and the ssh-rsa. Select 99 is your owner_id.

```
select * from public_key

select DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, GETDATE())

insert into public_key
  (owner_id, [name], fingerprint, content, mode, [type], created_unix, updated_unix)
  select 99, 'Umbraco Fyin.com', 'SHA256:NlTXCqPAfBq5VJcZsqpt0kvAFCcjmCs36oE88nhRT64', 'ssh-rsa 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 youremail@fyin.com', 2, 1, 1524623418, 0`
```

Comment: After struggling for few days, I decided to switch to mysql. Now everything is running fine. Thanks for your support.